# $T$ fails to be unconditionally converging if and only if there is a subspace $S$ of $X$ isomorphic to $c_0$ such that $T|_S$ is an isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Several books  state this theorem, for example:

1. Handbook of measure theory, volumen two, E. Pap, page 423
   [image]
2. Sequence and series in Banach spaces, 1984, Diestel, page 54 (here is exposed an as exercise)

[image]

I have proved the $"\Leftarrow"$ part. But im unable to prove  the converse.

Several other books refers to the original paper of Bessaga and Pelczynski " on bases and unconditional convergence of series in banach spaces" but I just couldn't find a link from their article to this proposition.

Any other reference would ve helpful. Thanks.